# Efficient data structure for searching numbers and strings

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have a scenario where in strings and numbers are combined into a single entity. I need to search based on the string or the number. How do I go about with the data structure for this?
I thought of coming up with a hashing for strings and search tree approach for numbers. Can you please comment on my choice and also suggest better structures if any?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on your "single entity" and give examples?

Comment: I think that depends very much of the number of strings and numbers you have. Usually, using the standard `std::map` or `tr1::unordered_map` do the trick without creating any ad-hoc structures.

Comment: by single entity, I mean, they'll be available as objects or as a part of structure. Please note that I can have millions of entries and hence, I need an optimised answer...

Comment: please restrict your answers to C++ domain.

Answer (score 1):

Use two `std::map`s, one from `std::string` to a pointer and the other from number to a pointer. The pointers go to your "single entity". See how far you can scale this (millions of entries...) before trying to optimize further.